# Solving $e^{\frac{x^2}{4vt}} = 1+\frac{x^2}{2vt}$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I need help with solving this difficult fluid dynamic expression. I have tried using rules of logs, symbolab algebra calculator and Wolfram Alpha calculator, and I have got no solution.

> How would you solve the following expression for $x$?
>   $$e^{\frac{x^2}{4vt}} = 1+\frac{x^2}{2vt}$$

When solving this numerically, the solution is: $x=2.2418\sqrt{vt}$

---

I want to know how you could solve the first expression to get the solution. So could someone please provide a step-by-step solution please?

Comment: If you move everything to one side and ask Wolfram Alpha, you get a rather nasty-looking result involving the Lambert W function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+0+%3D+e%5E((x%5E2)%2F4vt)+-+1+-+(x%5E2)%2F(2vt)

Comment: The expression you get is also much nastier than the numeric solution, so I think solving for $x$ might not be the way to go, because of how nontrivial it is.

Comment: Would you have to use use the Newton-Raphson formula?

Comment: x = 0 is a solution.

Comment: What are the parameter values for $v$,$t$? Looks like it could be a perturbation problem if $v t $ is large.

Comment: @DavidG you do not need the parameter values for v and t. This solution will be used to find the circulation value further down the line, which will eventually cancel out the values for v and t, however that is not part of this problem/question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$e^{\frac{x^2}{4vt}} = 1+\frac{x^2}{2vt}$$
Let $y=\frac{x^2}{4vt}$
$$e^y=1+2y$$
$$e^{-y}=\frac{1}{1+2y}$$
$$(1+2y)e^{-y}=1$$
$$(\frac12+y)e^{-y}=\frac12$$
$$(-\frac12-y)e^{-y}=-\frac12$$
$$ (-\frac12-y)e^{-y}e^{-\frac12}=-\frac12 e^{-\frac12}$$
$$ (-\frac12-y)e^{-\frac12-y}=-\frac12 e^{-\frac12}=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}$$
$X=(-\frac12-y)$
$$Xe^X=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}$$
From the definition of the Lambert W function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html
$$X=W\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)$$
$$y=-\frac12-X=-\frac12-W\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)$$
$$x=\sqrt{4vty}=\sqrt{-2-4W\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)}\sqrt{vt}$$
The Lambert W(z) function is a multi valuated function in $-\frac{1}{e} <z<0$ , real $z$.

This is presently the case where $z=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}$ since $-\frac{1}{e} <-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}<0$

First root :

$W_0\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)=-\frac12 \quad;\quad {-2-4W_0\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)}=-2-4(-1/2)=0 \quad;\quad x=0$

Second root :

$W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)\simeq -1.756431... $

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lambertw(-1,-1%2F(2+sqrt(e)))

One can use series expansion to compute it approximately. See page 13 in  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function . The convergence is very slow. See the numerical calculus in the below addition. In practice, it is certainly faster to solve directly $e^y=1+2y$ with Newton-Raphson or similar iterative method.

Finally, an approximate value is :

$$x\simeq\sqrt{-2-4(-1.756431)}\sqrt{vt}\simeq 2.2418128 \sqrt{vt}$$

With more digits : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(-2-4+lambertw(-1,-1%2F(2+sqrt(e))))

IN ADDITION :

Example of recursive numerical calculus of $W_{-1}(x)$ in the range $-\frac{1}{e}<x<0$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, clearly $x=0$ is a solution.

Also (*Mathematica*):

$$x = \pm \sqrt{2} \sqrt{-2 t v W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}\right)-t v}$$

Comment: Sorry pardon my ignorance, which special function is $W_n(x)$?

Comment: The Lambert W function or ProductLog.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function . http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProductLogFunction.html

Comment: Cheers @David G. Stork

Comment: How would you expand the Lamber W function to get $x=2.2418\sqrt{vt}$ @DavidG.Stork

Comment: @AlanGlenn:  I would merely evaluate it numerically, just as we do with innumerable other functions, such as $\sin$, $\log$, etc.